# Quartz with Asp.Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, quartz.net, .net-core-3.1

I am working on ASP.NET 3.1 Web Api project and I want to configure Quartz to schedule jobs which will work after 10 seconds. I need help in this because I setup quartz but job is not firing.
I installed 2 NuGet's

1. Quartz.AspNetCore (3.1.0)
2. Quartz.Extensions.DependencyInjection (3.1.0)

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {

   ```
           services.AddQuartz(q =>
           {
               q.SchedulerId = "Scheduler-Core";

               q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory(options =>
               {
                   // if we don't have the job in DI, allow fallback to configure via default constructor
                   options.AllowDefaultConstructor = true;
               });

               // these are the defaults
               q.UseSimpleTypeLoader();
               q.UseInMemoryStore();
               q.UseDefaultThreadPool(tp =>
               {
                   tp.MaxConcurrency = 10;
               });


               var jobKey = new JobKey("SchedulerJob", "SchedulerJob");
               q.AddJob<SchedulerJob>(j => j
                   .WithIdentity(jobKey)
                   .WithDescription("SchedulerJob")
               );

               q.AddTrigger(t => t
                       .WithIdentity("SchedulerJob Trigger")
                       .ForJob(jobKey)
                       .StartNow()
                       .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithInterval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).RepeatForever())
                       .WithDescription("SchedulerJob simple trigger")
                   );

               // base quartz scheduler, job and trigger configuration
           });

           // ASP.NET Core hosting
           services.AddQuartzServer(options =>
           {
               // when shutting down we want jobs to complete gracefully
               options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
           });

           services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
       }
   ```

Here is the job which i want to execute after evert 10 seconds.

```
public class SchedulerJob : IJob
    {
        private readonly ISendNotificationService _sendNotificationService;

        public SchedulerJob(ISendNotificationService sendNotificationService)
        {
            _sendNotificationService = sendNotificationService;
        }

        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _sendNotificationService.SendScheduledNotifications();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do the logs say? Empty catch also looks like trouble.

Comment: Job is not firing. Nothing happened.

Comment: Sounds about right based on the logs.